# Why am I getting two IP Addresses?

Tags: php, api, ip-address

**PROBLEM**

I working with php and an api to use the users IP to get the local currency. Its been working for a while now, but all of a sudden, my ISP keeps giving me two ip addresses.

Normally if i echo `$ipaddress`, I get something like `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` so it passes the API like this

```
https://usercountry.com/v1.0/json/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx?token=<API KEY>
```

but recently  `$ipaddress` is giving me two IPs(Different IP addresses) like this `xxx.xxx.xxx,yyy.yyy.yyy`

so now it passes the API like this 
    `https://usercountry.com/v1.0/json/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy?token=<API KEY>`

which returns an error because UserCountry.com do not allow double IP

I use this check anytime the Double IP happens

```
if (strlen($ipaddress) > 15){
     $ipaddress = "Double IP";
}
```

**My Analysis**

```
$ipaddress= xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

When it happens, the first IP `(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)` seems like the real one(the IP is in the same country as I ), But the second IP `(yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy)` isn't in the same country with me,

**What I Want**

So I want to write a php code to echo only the first IP address `(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)` from `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy`

Thank You

**Edit**

Some people want to know how i get the IP address to `$ipaddress`

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

When I use http://ip-api.com/ to check my IP address, I actually get two IP addresses
`xxx.xxx.xxx,yyy.yyy.yyy`

Comment: `$ipaddress` is not a variable that will be set by default in a PHP program. There is no way to tell why you are getting any particular value without at least knowing how you assign a it a value in the first place.

Comment: i have written a function to get users IP address and pass it into the `$ipaddress` variable

Comment: ...then you might want to show us that function? We're not here to guess.

Comment: BTW: Your question's ambiguity already caused people to give different answers, depending on whether they reply to the topic of your question or your description. Make that consistent! Also, ask yourself whether all the background is necessary for your question.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ,  i just edited the question and added it

Comment: And which one of those if/elses if giving the double values?

Comment: @Quentin i'm not sure, but as i said www.ip-api.com also shows me two IPs. I could have checked now to be sure, but like i said, it doesn't happens always

Comment: "i'm not sure — So debug it and find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the IP that you are getting is using some kind of proxy.
Try splitting the IP with (,) using the PHP `explode` method, then choose the first one.

```
$ips = explode(',', $ipaddress);
$theOneYouWant = $ips[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ipaddress = explode(',', $ipaddress)[0];
```

> Explode returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries…

**But beware:** Choosing the array-entry directly on the function line does — not — work before PHP 5.4.

The industry term for that is `array dereferencing`.

[Before PHP 5.4 you need to use the answer by @muttalebm.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49474493/2569323)

Comment: The question is _why_ the OP gets two IP's, not how to work with it. (Not my down vote. just sayin').

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Why? **What I Want** says differently.

Comment: Not saying that your answer is wrong on how to deal with it, but If you look at the title, it asks why since it just started to happen. Before we should give the OP an answer at all, the OP needs to show us how they are fetching the IP in the first place.

Comment: It works!!
 @MagnusEriksson I did ask how to work with it, maybe its not the right way to go, but I'm not sure i can do anything about why my ISP gives me two IPs

Comment: @staynjokede — We certainly can't help you with that if you insist on keeping the code which gets them a secret.

Comment: @Quentin i edited it, i've added how i get the ip address